# Mistake deleting disk partition

Tags: windows

I am a newbie and while I was trying to install Linux on a boot partition, I have mistakenly erased this 128MB Windows 11 partition.

Windows seems to work fine, but what should I do ? What did I erase?? How can I restore it?

[image: Disk management screenshot]